# Compare SQL scalar function result to a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
select 
    x1.name, x1.owner,
    (Select dbo.GetTopEmployerName(x1.unit)),
    X2.searchName, x4.code,x6.status
From 
    dbo.profile X1
Join 
    dbo.profilevalues x3 on X1.profileId == x3.profileKey
Left outer join 
    dbo.profilecontact X2 on x1.unit = X2.ctId
Join 
    dbo.accessright x4 on x3.accessrightsId == x4.accessrightId
Left outer join 
    dbo.profilecontact x5 on x1.owner = x5.contactId
Left outer join 
    dbo.status x6 on x1.statusId = x6.statusId
Where
    ((X4.accessRightid in (200,300,400);
    ))
```

Here I need to compare the result of function i.e `dbo.GetTopEmployerName()` with `x4.code`.

I need to check if they are not same.

Comment: Left justified SQL is just so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: x1, x2 etc are poor table aliases. Chose aliases that make sense, like `p` for `profile`.

Comment: Hint: Use a cte, or derived table.

Comment: Also: **do not** use two equal sign in SQL - one is just fine! So `on X1.profileId == x3.profileKey` should properly be `on X1.profileId = x3.profileKey`

Comment: is it not just a comparison like `x4_code =  (Select dbo.GetTopEmployerName(x1.unit))` ? if only the function returns only one value I mean

Comment: @SUJITMOHANTY30 it works that way but will that be efficient performance wise?

Comment: Jarlh and marc_s thank you for your suggestions, will make sure next time

Comment: Don't now much with respect to SQL server but yes could be if we expect more number of rows and another option would be to put onto CTE as @jarlh suggested.  or you could use of `Deterministic` function if the value for one particular `x1.unit` is fixed... need to explore if you as me....but  as I see its a table which store `Profile` information you don't expect the result set bigger . am I right ?

Comment: The value of x1.unit is not fixed and there are huge amount of information in lakhs. And I cannot as well change the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your query up in a *derived table*:

```
select name, owner, TopEmployerName, searchName, code, status
from
(
    select 
        x1.name, x1.owner,
        (Select dbo.GetTopEmployerName(x1.unit)) TopEmployerName,
        X2.searchName, x4.code, x6.status
    From 
        dbo.profile X1
    Join 
        dbo.profilevalues x3 on X1.profileId == x3.profileKey
    Left outer join 
        dbo.profilecontact X2 on x1.unit = X2.ctId
    Join 
        dbo.accessright x4 on x3.accessrightsId == x4.accessrightId
    Left outer join 
        dbo.profilecontact x5 on x1.owner = x5.contactId
    Left outer join 
        dbo.status x6 on x1.statusId = x6.statusId
    Where
        X4.accessRightid in (200,300,400)
) dt
where TopEmployerName = code
```